# Proof of Projective Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

In the proof of the Nullstellensatz for projective varieties, I can't understand the following remark (which comes from Hulek, Elementary algebraic geometry, pag. 72)

" ... if $f=\sum f_i$ is a polynomial with homogeneous components $f_i$ then (using the fact that the field $k$ has infinitely many elements) $f(\lambda x_0,\ldots,\lambda x_n)=0$ for all $\lambda$ if and only if $f_i(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=0$ for all $i$...."

The *only if* part is trivial. I can't understand the *if* part. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Can you see why the equality $f_i(\lambda x_0,\ldots,\lambda x_n)=\lambda^if_i(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ holds for all $i$?

Comment: Yes, because $f_i$ are homogeneous!

Comment: @DanaeKissinger: Exactly.  Now apply this fact to the sum of the $f_i$, which is $f$.

Comment: D'oh, I can consider the RHS has a polynomial in $\lambda$, and since it has infinitely many roots, it must be the zero polynomial thus its coefficients (the $f_i(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ ) are all zero!! Does it make sense??

Comment: @DanaeKissinger: You got it.  Nice work.